# datetime comparison on iis7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

i am creating an web application, where i need to compare two date and time (even second also).

i am using following code for that:

```
//Check for delete button
                DateTime dtmEndDate;
                DateTime.TryParse(dtCommunication.Rows[0]["DateEnd"].ToString(), out dtmEndDate);

                if (dtmEndDate<=DateTime.Now)
                {

                //}
                //if DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(),dtmEndDate.ToLocalTime()) >= 0)
                //{
                    btnSend.Visible = false;
                    btnBack.Visible = false;

                    btnDelete.Visible = true;
                    btnCancel.Visible = true;         
                }
```

if EndDate datetime has been elapsed, then it will go inside if block.

This working fine locally, but when i upload the code on the server, its not working accordingly. How i can handle  this?

Example:
dtmEndDate= 12/27/2012 7:00 PM 
Current Indian time =12/27/2012 8:00 PM
Current Sever Time=12/27/2012 8:30 AM

above are the scenario.

Comment: Have you debugged it on the server? **[Remote debug](http://mvolo.com/debugging-iis-70-web-applications-remotely-with-visual-studio-2008)** is your friend.

Comment: What are the dates you are expecting?  Have you confirmed the database returns a valid date (via whatever SQL editor you use outside your application)?

Comment: @Wonko the Sane  : its coming to label text correctly.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily answer the question.  Are you formatting the date for the label?  You need to know absolitely what the value of dtmEndDate is.  There isn't much sense of calling TryParse if you aren't going to check the return value - you are just hiding errors.

Comment: If you're working across time zones I would *strongly* suggest you use UTC for all `DateTime`s -- at least internally (convert input from user / for output to user if required).
You can have `DateTime`s that are both `Local` (or `Unspecified`), but if they are coming from different TZ's then comparing them doesn't make much sense.  Not sure that that's a contributing factor here but trust me UTC is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

TryParse returns false if it tried and failed.

```
DateTime dtmEndDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dtCommunication.Rows[0]["DateEnd"].ToString(), out dtmEndDate))
{
   // okey dokey
}
else
{
   throw new SomeException(String.Format("{0} is not a valid date",dtCommunication.Rows[0]["DateEnd"].ToString());
}
```

would be a good start. A guess would be dateend is blank, not a date or not a date in a format the application is set up for. Have a look at ParseExact, and the System.Globalisation namespace's CultureInfo.

Comment: On the server? All the time? This one looks like a classic erroneous assumption to me. Can't really help you more without more information, beef the code up, output to the log inside if and else statements, get a clear picture of what's going on. Don't assume anything. Either small blue rigellians have popped in to play a practical joke on you, or you are going to be doing a Homer Simpson impression. My experience suggests a very convincing Doh! is more likely.

Comment: i have added an example of time. please see the question again.

Comment: Looks like @David called it with UTC then.